# How do i prove that $f(x,y)=x e^{-x^2(1+y^2)}$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How do i prove that $f(x,y)=x e^{-x^2(1+y^2)}$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$ or Borel measurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: As far as i know, it's not of the form $f\circ g$. What do you mean it's a conposite?

Comment: The individual functions involved include things like $(a,b) \mapsto a+b$, $(a,b) \mapsto ab$, $t \mapsto e^t$ and such. You may find it easier to compute the limit as $(x,y) \mapsto (a,b)$, and see that the whole thing can be done with limit laws.

Comment: Thank you. Here's how i proved it following your advise. Let $\Phi:(x,y)\rightarrow xy$ be a binary mapping. This function is continuous. Let $f,g$ Be continuous functions. Define $F(x,y)=\Phi(f(x),g(y))$. Then using $\epsilon-delta$ criteria, it can be shown thay $F(x,y)$ is continuous. Is this what you meant?